# JQuery + .show()

Tags: jquery, show

This is a simple example of radio buttons using JQuery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg6Qb/25/)

So what I want is to be able to slowly display the radio buttons something like this:

[JSFiddle - show()](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg6Qb/26/)

but instead of having .html here I want to slowly fade it in

```
$("#answer").html(answers);
```

something like

```
$("#answer").show('slow');
```

but i can't quite work it out. Can someone please advise?

Comment: this is a good resource  [http://jqueryui.com/show/](http://jqueryui.com/show/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var allButtons = [["Milk", "Butter", "Cheese"],["Water", "Beer", "Wine"]];
var index=0;

$("#nextbutton").on("click", function () {

    var answers = '';
    $(allButtons[index]).each(function (i) {
        answers += '<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + allButtons[index][i] + '">' + allButtons[index][i] + '<br>'
    });

    answers=answers+"index = " + index;
    $("#answer").hide();
    $("#answer").html(answers);
    $("#answer").show('slow')


    index+=1;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg6Qb/31/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var allButtons = [["Milk", "Butter", "Cheese"],["Water", "Beer", "Wine"]];
var index=0;

function displayOption($ct, array, index){
    if(array.length <= index){
        return;
    }

    var opt = array[index];
    $('<div/>').append('<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + opt + '">' + opt).hide().appendTo($ct).fadeIn(function(){
        displayOption($ct, array, index + 1);
    });

}

jQuery(function($){
    $("#nextbutton").on("click", function () {
        var $answers = $("#answer");

        $answers.empty();

        displayOption($answers, allButtons[index], 0);
        index++;
    });

})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a7XWw/)

Comment: tks that's even better than what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

Modified the span to initially be `display: none`

```
<span id="answer" style="display: none">possible answers will go here...</span>
```

Then, in the click handler, keep the current logic and, at the end, call .show(…) on the span:

```
$("#nextbutton").on("click", function () {

    var answers = '';
    $(allButtons[index]).each(function (i) {
        answers += '<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + allButtons[index][i] + '">' + allButtons[index][i] + '<br>'
    });

    answers = answers + "index = " + index;

    $("#answer").html(answers);
    $("#answer").show('slow');
    index += 1;
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg6Qb/30/)

Comment: Yes - it overrides the locally set style.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works. Simply hide the element, and show it again all in one go.

```
$("#answer").hide().html(answers).show('slow');
```

The full code from JSFiddle

```
var allButtons = [["Milk", "Butter", "Cheese"],["Water", "Beer", "Wine"]];
var index=0;

$("#nextbutton").on("click", function () {

    var answers = '';
    $(allButtons[index]).each(function (i) {
        answers += '<input type="radio" name="group1' + '" value="' + allButtons[index][i] + '">' + allButtons[index][i] + '<br>'
    });

    answers=answers+"index = " + index;

    $("#answer").hide().html(answers).show('slow');

    index+=1;
});
```